# How to remove multiple F-Curve animation Modifiers

Tags: animation, curve-modifier

For some reason there is no plausible way to batch remove f-curve modifiers from multiple curves.
There is a way to do it for 'CYCLIC' modifiers, but no for others.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of ChatGPT, I managed to create an Add-On that adds a button that does exactly this job:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Delete multiple F-Curve modifiers",
    "author": "Serj Maiorov, ChatGPT",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 90, 0),
    "location": "Graph Editor > Modifiers",
    "description": "This add-on allows you to delete F-Curve modifiers on selected or all animation curves. Also randomize the offset property on multiple Noise modifiers. Yo can find it above the Animation modifiers panel",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "Animation",
}

import bpy
import random

class GRAPH_PT_Modifiers(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "F-Modifiers"
    bl_idname = "GRAPH_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'GRAPH_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Modifiers'
    bl_options = {'HIDE_HEADER'}

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(context.scene, "chk", text="Selected Curves")
        col.operator("my_custom_operator.run_script", text="Delete Modifiers")
        col.operator("my_custom_operator.randomize_modifiers", text="Random Offset Noise Modifier")

class DeleteModifiers_Operator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "my_custom_operator.run_script"
    bl_label = "Delete Modifiers"

    def execute(self, context):
        selected_objects = bpy.context.selected_objects
        chk = context.scene.chk
        for obj in selected_objects:
            if obj.animation_data:
                action = obj.animation_data.action
                for fcurve in action.fcurves:
                    if chk == True:
                        if fcurve.select:
                            for modifier in fcurve.modifiers:
                                fcurve.modifiers.remove(modifier)
                    else:
                        for modifier in fcurve.modifiers:
                            fcurve.modifiers.remove(modifier)

        bpy.context.view_layer.update()
        return {'FINISHED'}

class RandomizeModifiers_Operator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "my_custom_operator.randomize_modifiers"
    bl_label = "Randomize Modifiers"

    def execute(self, context):
        chk = context.scene.chk
        min_value = -1000.0
        max_value = 1000
        for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
            for anim_data in obj.animation_data.action.fcurves:
                if chk == True:
                    if anim_data.select:
                        for modifier in anim_data.modifiers:
                            if modifier.type == 'NOISE':
                                modifier.offset = random.uniform(min_value, max_value)
                else:
                    for modifier in anim_data.modifiers:
                        if modifier.type == 'NOISE':
                            modifier.offset = random.uniform(min_value, max_value)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(GRAPH_PT_Modifiers)
    bpy.utils.register_class(DeleteModifiers_Operator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(RandomizeModifiers_Operator)
    bpy.types.Scene.chk = bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Checkbox", default=True)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(GRAPH_PT_Modifiers)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(DeleteModifiers_Operator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(RandomizeModifiers_Operator)
    del bpy.types.Scene.chk

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Also added a batch randomize for 'NOISE' modifier's offset.

Just save this text to a .py file and install it like a regular add-on.

Hope it will help somebody because it wasn't easy for me to find a solution on the web

Comment: so it began , i literally spend last 2 weeks doing this. AIpocalypse! But honestly, if it solves the problem then i gladly copypaste it